# consolidate items in datagridview visual basic.net 2008

Tags: vb.net

```
 Dim X As String
 Dim V, Q, Y As Double
DGV.ColumnCount = 3
 con.Open()
cmd = New SqlCommand("select Name,Price from Items where Name ='" & ListItems.SelectedItem & "'", con)
DR = cmd.ExecuteReader
While DR.Read()
    ' Q = Val(Qty.Text)
    X = (DR("Name").ToString())
    Y = Val((DR("Price").ToString()))
    V = Q * Y
    Dim row As String() = New String() {Q, X, V}
    DGV.Rows.Add(row)
```

i am using visual basic.net and if i have similar items in datagridview as below
for example

```
1 hot dog 5 $
2 hot dog 10 $
5 hot dog 20 $
```

how can we consolidate them in one line as

8 hot dog 40 $

Comment: So the individual items are on separate rows. Do you want to press a button and their consolidation is viewed on a label? Or viewed on a final "total" row?

Comment: On a final total row

Answer (score 0):

So you have columns "Name" and "Price". From your text under your code I see that name is going to be "5 hotdog" and Price to be "20$". I don't know if they are formatted that way, but I am going to assume so.

So what you want to do first is calculate the values you want in your "total" row. Since you have "hot dog" or a string after your initial number, we want to just get that number for each value. We'll loop through, evaluate that number, and sum it up. We'll do the same with the price column, but instead we'll remove the "$" in the string. Again, I'm doing a lot of assuming here.

```
    Dim nameTotal As Integer = 0
    Dim priceTotal As Integer = 0

    'loop through each row of the DGV
    For Each row As DataRow In DGV.Rows

        'evaluate value in current row
        Dim str_nameValue As String = row.Item("Name").ToString()
        str_nameValue = str_nameValue.Remove(" hot dog")

        'or if there are other string attached, remove those from the str_nameValue here to get an integer
        'processing stringcode here...

        'add to name total 
        nameTotal += CInt(str_nameValue)

        'do the same for the other column
        Dim str_priceValue As String = row.Item("Price").ToString()
        str_priceValue = str_priceValue.Remove("$")

        'sum
        priceTotal += CInt(str_priceValue)
    Next

    'for loop is finished, add a new row with the values 

    'add row to table with a parameter of total values, and an empty one for the second column 
    DGV.Rows.Add(nameTotal & " hot dog " & priceTotal & "$", " ")
```

You should be in charge of formatting your strings to meet your needs.

Comment: it gives me error this error(  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.)

Comment: I think the loop should start `For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGV.Rows`